# Unauthorized transaction from Ronin Wallet

Tags: transactions, wallets, sendtransaction

I'm facing a big problem related to my Ronin Wallet, i bought ETH as usual and trying to send it to Axie Infinity, but after i got the ETH i bought, another random transaction appeared as if i transferred it to another account, **i didn't did that**, it was a hack i think, is there anything i can do to get my ETH back from this? [image]

There the transaction that says **"4 HOURS AGO"** is the one that i didn't did! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the transaction was initiated by another wallet (using `transferFrom`). If thats the case cancel all your approvals and you should be fine (im assuming tokens on the chain you're on work the same way they do on ethereum, if thats not the case my answer is irrelevant and im sorry). If no that means someone has direct control over your wallet and you should really transfer all your tokens to another wallet and stop using this one.